Visualizing 3D GeoJSON in threejs
I have a 3D GeoJSON of a 3D city model. I want to display it in Three.js, but it does not support this format.
Is there a method or plugin that can load the 3D GeoJSON in Three.js? Below is the file I am working on.
geojson file in this question
